# Does deeplinking in iOS need something to do on server side?

Tags: ios, deep-linking

I am trying to implement deeplinking in iOS.
After a little research i came to know the if we need to navigate to our app(if installed) on click of a link, we need to work on server side also.
Is there anyway to work out this without server side dependency?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to link to your app:

### Make iOS redirect URLs of your website to your app (Universal Links)

For example `http://maps.apple.com/?q=1+Infinite+Loop` opens the Maps App and YouTube-Links redirect to the YouTube-App, if it is installed.

This requires some server-side configuration.

I have not worked with Universal Links yet, so I can just propose you to read [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) by Apple about this topic.

### Use a custom URL scheme

If you don't want to do anything on your server, you need to use a custom URL-scheme like `myapp://this/is/a/url`

Comment: If app is not on phone then i want to open App Store link; Can it be possible without involving server? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The old-fashioned approach to deep linking used custom URI schemes, which didn't require any server-side implementation. [These don't work well anymore](https://blog.branch.io/ios-9.2-redirection-update-uri-scheme-and-universal-links). Apple introduced [Universal Links](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-universal-links-to-deep-link-on-apple-ios-9) in iOS 9, which *do* require a server-side update.

If you don't want to deal with all the implementation details, check out [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team). It's a free service that takes care of all this without any server requirements from you.

Comment: If app installed then open app and if app not installed then open App Store link of the app. Is it possible without involving server side implementation? Thanks

Comment: Not reliably, no. Universal Links require server side config, and they are the only correct option in many situations